# Force a JFrame in a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, sorting, jframe, jpanel

Can I force a `JFrame` to be drawn inside a `JPanel`?

Because I'm getting a new frame from a foreign class which visualises a sorting algorithm. I'm building a GUI where you can pick a sorting algorithm from a list and press the start button and then the visualization should happen inside my GUI panel and not in the foreign window.

Comment: This method might help you: [JFrame#getContentPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#getContentPane%28%29)

Comment: Hopefully you've well separated your model-view-control code. If so, then choosing where to draw what should be easy. Otherwise, you've got some difficulty ahead, and so do we, since you'll likely need to provide more information with your question including details and code.

Comment: Our professor gave us many libraries. And we had to implement sorting algorithms like bubble sort, heap sort and so on. And one of the Classes he gave us was called Storage. In which the data was stored we had to sort. Creating a new Storage object creates a new JFrame where the visualization of our sorting algorithm is shown. After learning something about GUI my intention was to create a little "terminal" where you can choose a sorting algorithm and press the start button. That works. But the algorithm is started in the Storage JFrame and I want to force it in my GUI.

Comment: If the current answer has solved your question, then great -- accept it by clicking on the large check mark to the left of it and move on. If not, then you'll still want to improve this question by showing pertinent code and providing more detail about that code and your proposed code.

Answer (score 2):

you could try to use a **javax.swing.JInternalFrame** and add it to a **javax.swing.JDesktopPane** as shown [Java Swing Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html) or [here](http://java-buddy.blogspot.fr/2014/02/example-of-using-jinternalframe.html) for example.
Basically :

```
    ...//In the constructor of InternalFrameDemo, a JFrame subclass:
    desktop = new JDesktopPane();
    createFrame(); //Create first window
    setContentPane(desktop);
    ...
    //Make dragging a little faster but perhaps uglier.
    desktop.setDragMode(JDesktopPane.OUTLINE_DRAG_MODE);
...
protected void createFrame() {
    MyInternalFrame frame = new MyInternalFrame();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    desktop.add(frame);
    try {
        frame.setSelected(true);
    } catch (java.beans.PropertyVetoException e) {}
}
```

Does that answer to your question ?